# Create an angular service that acts like an OO class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a network service that answers "Widgets", and each of them has a large array of simpler objects, "parts", that need to be fetched separately.  I want to expose this as an angular service that fetches widgets -- and parts for some of them -- and caches the results in localStorage, but I'm running into problems (noted in the code, then below)...

```
angular.module('myApp').service('myWidgetService', function ($q, requestService, localStorageService, _) {

    // start everything off by fetching the Widgets, saving locally
    this.refresh = function() {
        var self = this;
        return requestService.request('GET', '/api/widget/', true).then(function(result) {
            self.setCloudArray(result);
            // I want callers to use "Widget instances" defined below
            return _.map(result, function(cloudItem) { return new Widget(cloudItem); });
        });
    };

    // get and set persistent widget array
    this.cloudArray = function() {
        return localStorageService.get('cloudArray');
    };

    this.setCloudArray = function(cloudArray) {
        localStorageService.set('cloudArray', cloudArray);
    };

    // I want this "Widget instance" to provide methods related to a single widget
    var Widget = function(cloudItem) {
        this.cloudItem = cloudItem;  // PROBLEM A:  (this indirection hurts me later)
    };

    // get the parts, but only if they haven't been fetched already
    // if they've been fetched, return the cached copy
    Widget.prototype.parts = function() {
        var self = this.cloudItem;  // weirdness due to PROBLEM A
        if (self.parts) { return $q.when(self.parts); }
        var route = '/api/widget/' + self._id + '/parts';
        return requestService.request('GET', route, true).then(function(result) {
            self.parts = result;  // PROBLEM B: how to persist?
            return result;
        });
    };

    Widget.prototype.partWithId = function(id) {
        return _.find(this.cloudItem.parts, function(part) { return part._id === id; });
    };

});
```

The two problems I'm having are flagged in the code.

PROBLEM A: I don't really want to add a cloudItem property to my Widget.  In a widget method, I want to say things like `this.foo` for the `foo` property of the object, but I'm forced to say `this.cloudItem.foo`.

PROBLEM B: The bigger problem is that the call for a widget's parts is expensive, and I want to cache the result.  But the thing that local storage knows about is an array of objects that my instance "cloudItem" is a member of.  I don't know an elegant way to do that save from within my widget object.

I've written an inelegant method at the class level like this to update local storage:

```
this.saveWidget = function(updatedWidget) {
    var cloudArray = this.cloudArray();
    var currentItem = _.find(cloudArray, function(i) { return i._id === updatedWidget._id; });
    var index = cloudArray.indexOf(currentItem);
    cloudArray[index] = updatedWidget;
    this.setCloudArray(cloudArray);
};
```

which I call after fetching the parts.  This works, but though I'm not too experienced with JS and web development, I know enough to know that I'm digging myself into a hole.  I've read a bunch of stuff about services and JS objects, but it's clear I'm missing something important.

How can I avoid the extra indirection in my Widget object and give it a more direct, more OO way to save itself to local storage?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Curious why you don't store the widgets as object instead of array. Much simpler and cheaper to get an object property than loop through array to find it

Comment: @charlietfl - do you mean instantiate an array of widgets and save that?  This is evidence of my dumbness, but I resisted that because I was unsure about saving the "prototype" stuff (the functions) for the objects in local storage.    It's another part of JS that confuses me, I guess.

Comment: Ahh, or maybe @charlietfl,  you're saying I should save the state (cloudItem) by id in the local storage?  That's  good idea.  Maybe do that in the constructor, then I can write a save method at the instance level.  That's a big help already.

Comment: Could do that...one widget per storage item or what I was alluding to is storing in memory/storage as `{"wdget-name-1": {/*widget 1 data*/}, "wdget-name-2": {/*widget 2 data*/}}` which saves looping through array to find things. Object properties are infinitely faster to access

Comment: Yes, thanks. That is smarter.  I'll do that, but I think I'm still stuck with the basic problems as outlined, improved by indexing at the top level but essentially the same, right?

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand what initial problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned two things that helped me solve this:  `angular.extend()` fixes my first problem....

```
var Widget = function(cloudItem) {
    angular.extend(this, cloudItem);
    // replaces
    // this.cloudItem = cloudItem;  // PROBLEM A:  (this indirection hurts me later)
};
```

Thanks to extend() (and hidden magic that returns 'this'), I don't need a 'cloudItem' attribute.

In my second problem, that I was lost trying to save state at the object level.  I think I just have to live with the fact that saving happens at the class level.

I improved things a bit with an object level save method (and persisting an indexed object rather than an array, thanks to a suggestion by @charlietfl)

```
// replaces the awkward: this.saveWidget = function(updatedWidget) I had before
Widget.prototype.save = function() {
    var cloudArray = localStorageService.get('cloudArray');
    // really a cloud object, thanks to suggestion by @charlietfl
    cloudArray[this._id] = this;
    localStorageService.set('cloudArray', cloudArray);
};
```

At least I can pretend save() makes sense to me.  This method on the instance hides the (ugly, imo) fact that saving is really mucking around at the class level.

Javascript is weird.